# creating ARM template for storage devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I try to create a storage account via a devops pipeline.

So I have this yaml file:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'spn-azure--contributor-002'
    subscriptionId: 'fea4c865-1e54-44b3-ba1d-07315468f083'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-idn-'
    location: 'West Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '**/template.json'
    csmParametersFile: '**/parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'spn-azure--contributor-002'
    subscriptionId: 'fea4c865-1e54-44b3-ba1d-07315468f083'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-idn-'
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: ARMTemplates/storage/azuredeploy.json
    csmParametersFile: ARMTemplates/storage/azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

Comment: You placed `minimumTlsVersion` in the wrong place, it should be under `properties` (see the doc I shared, last link). Same goes for `supportsHttpsTrafficOnly`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview) blocking your deployment here - meaning that your ARM template does not meet the rules of this policy. Someone from your organization most probably implemented this one to make sure that you are complying to specific security / architecture standards.

You can see it from the error message : `Error Type: PolicyViolation, Policy Definition Name : ESLZ Storage Account set to minimum TLS and Secure transfer should be enabled, Policy Assignment Name : ALZ_DeployEncrTLS.`. You should be able to retrieve it under your Subscription / Resource Group, in the Policy blade.

Basically, and this is an assumption as we would need to look into that specific policy, but you most likely have to specify an TLS version here (probably 1.2, to be checked in the policy) and enable secure transfer.

For this you need to set `minimumTlsVersion` to the correct version and `supportsHttpsTrafficOnly` to `true` within your ARM template. You can have a look at [Storage Account ARM specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts?tabs=json).

Comment: You have a typo in your ARM template, its explicitly highlighted in the error message : `Ensure the Template file ( '/home/vsts/work/1/s/ARMTemplates/storage/azuredeploy.json' ) is valid. Task failed while parsing with following error: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1420`